# Spring security: При вводе логина и пароля выкидывает ошибку Reason: user is disabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Вот код в котором проходит авторизация.

```
 @Autowired
public void configureSecurity(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
               .usersByUsernameQuery("select user_name, user_password_hash, user_id from rs_user where user_name=?")
               .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_name, user_is_administrator, user_id from rs_user where user_name=?");
}

/**
 * Configure http.
 * @param http of HttpSecurity type
 * @throws Exception of authentication exception
 */
@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().successHandler(savedRequest())
            .usernameParameter("login")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().csrf().disable().rememberMe().tokenRepository(persistenceTokenReposetory())
            .tokenValiditySeconds(400000000);
}
```

Из-за чего возникает эта ошибка? Возможно проблема в csrf, или я сформировал неправильный запрос?
Логин и пароль тяну из БД PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) у пользователя имеется свойство `enabled`. Однако в твоих sql'никах нет его выборки, следовательно по умолчанию оно равно `false`. Тебе надо добавить выборку этого свойства в sql'ник. Если хочешь, чтобы оно всегда было как `true`, то добавить надо `true as enabled`. В итоге получится примерно

```
.authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_name, user_is_administrator, user_id, true as enabled from rs_user where user_name=?");
```